# Integrate $\int \sqrt{a + x^3}dx$

Tags: integration

How does one go about integrating:

$$\int\sqrt{a + x^3}dx$$

Wolframalpha seems to be giving a result that seems slightly too [elaborate](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB%28%28a%20%2b%20x%5E3%29%5E1/2%29%20dx).

Comment: For $a\ne 0$, there probably is no antiderivative expressible in terms of "elementary" functions. Presumably Alpha used elliptic functions in its answer.

Answer (score -2):

why not use u-substitution?  u = a+x^3 then du=3x^2 dx.  Should be a good start.

Comment: This does not suffice, since we do not have a _promising_ way of rewriting the integral in terms of $u$. (Edited for technical accuracy due to DonAntonio's comment.)

Comment: Well, it doesn't look very promising, does it? Just take into account that $$dx=\frac{1}{3x^2}du=\frac{du}{3(u-a)^{2/3}}\,...$$